# php loop through fraction

Tags: php, math

I haven't written any code yet because i don't know where to start.

I have a RX Prescription form that Doctor's fill out to create a "New Prescription". I need to write a check to make sure what they fill out is actually possible. There are 4 variables they fill out: Quantity, MG per Dose, Dosages per Day, Prescribed Date.

For example, I need to make sure that if a Doctor fills out a RX for: 10 total pills, 1MG per dose & 3 Dosages per day, that it will return an error. It would error because after 3 days the Patient would only have 1 Pill left (3 per day * 3 days = 9 total dosages).

I need to make sure that the prescription makes sense, and that whatever they fill out is mathematically possible. My guess is to write a PHP Loop, but the math is sadly very fuzzy to me. Any help is greatly appreciated. This is the final functionality for my project before it goes "Live".

Comment: Modulus might be a useful tool for checking the viability of a prescription http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: It's not very clear what you are looking for. I don't understand the logic for how you are checking for errors.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg The goal is to not write out a bad prescription. The doctor says "Take two pills/day for 10 days", but then accidentally writes the prescription for 18 pills. The system shouldn't allow this. Not sure how the mg dosage factors in...that would be an exercise for the OP.

Comment: +1 because I disagree with the downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you basically saying you want to find out if the total number of pills is wholly divisible by the number of days?  Do you know the number of days the prescription is for?  If so:

```
if($totalNumberOfPills % $numberOfDays == 0) {
   // Sound.
}
```

Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you are asking.

Comment: May I suggest `$numberOfDays * $pillsPerDay` ?

Comment: Yes, I have the total number of days. I generate an "expiration date" based off of this information. That is EXACTLY what I'm trying to do, but the terminology escaped me, and I've never written anything like this before.

Answer (score 1):

From your example:

> A Doctor fills out a RX for: 10 total pills, 1MG per dose & 3 Dosages
>   per day, that it will return an error. It would error because after 3
>   days the Patient would only have 1 Pill left (3 per day * 3 days = 9
>   total dosages).

I understand that you need to make sure that the `The Total number of pills` is a multiple of the `Dosages per day`.

You can check that easily with the `%` operator:

```
if($totalNumberOfPills % $pillsPerDay == 0)
{
    //Ok
}
else
{
    //Not Ok
}
```

You can also calculate how many days those pills will last:

```
$numberOfDays = $totalNumberOfPills/$pillsPerDay;
```

And if this number is not integer, well, you know the values aren't right.

```
if(is_int($numberOfDays))
{
    //Ok
}
else
{
    //Not Ok
}
```